# How can I have GROUP_CONCAT data displayed separated

Tags: php, mysql, sql, backend

brands:

| brandId | brandName |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | apple |

products:

| productId | productName | brand |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | iPhone | apple |
| 2 | Macbook | apple |
| 3 | iMac | apple |

```
SELECT brands.brandId, brands.brandName, GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT(products.productName ) SEPARATOR ', ') AS product FROM brands
                JOIN products ON brands.brandName = products.brand GROUP BY brands.brandName
```

The Result of the code :

| brandId | brandName | product |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | apple | iPhone, Macbook, iMac |

Now I want to display them like this:

product: iPhone

product: Macbook

product: iMac

But this is the result I get:

products: iPhone, Macbook, iMac

How exactly can I fix this problem you don't have to worry about the quality of the code.

Comment: Do group concat on concatenation `'product :' || productName`

Comment: I don't know why but when I do that the output is only " 1 "

Comment: Of course, `concat('product :', productName)` for MySQL. [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=7daa053204ccf74cc1eecec5f7d9e43d)

Comment: Ok I was doing it wrong thanks for the help

Comment: some databases use `||` for concatenation, which is why someone erroneously suggested it, but in mysql it is a logical OR operator; it will return one if your productName starts with a non-zero number

Comment: You should be grouping by the brandID. It's probably indexed.

Comment: @ysth `which is why someone erroneously suggested it` ... MySQL in fact does support `||` for string concatenation, when running in ANSI mode.

Answer (score 0):

I think you just want `CONCAT` here along with `ORDER BY`:

```sql
SELECT
    b.brandId,
    CONCAT('product: ', p.productName) product
FROM brands b
INNER JOIN products p
    ON b.brandName = p.brand
ORDER BY
    b.brandId,
    p.productId;
```

Comment: Can I ask you what if I didn't want the part ' product: ' to repeat

Comment: That sounds like something you should handle in the PHP layer.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen It's because the group by was dropped off this query. That's why rows repeat.

Comment: @MichaelZ. That's not what the OP's comment is about, and the query you posted below is wrong.